# How to add a dot(.) in the url in yii2?

Tags: yii2

I was trying to add a dot in my URL in yii2. I am using Url rules for this.

Right now my URL looks like this.

`http://localhost:8000/user/auth_key`

But i want to change it to this

`http://localhost:8000/.user/auth_key`

My url-rules.php file looks like this.

```
<?php
    return [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'rules' => [
            'user/auth_key' => 'user/authentication'
        ]
   ];
?>
```

without the **dot(.)** the URL works fine. But I need a **dot(.)** in URL.
Does yii2 allow us to do this? How can I achieve this?
Any suggestions or help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `Yii` will treat the pattern `'.user/auth_key'` as plain text, you can use it directly.

The full rule would be:

```php
return [
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'rules' => [
        '.user/auth_key' => 'user/authentication'
    ]
];
```